# Read Xml date value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, date

I'm trying to pull DATE value from an XML column of SQL table. Below is the sample data i have in xml column. I'm trying to get\read DATE using XQuery Value function.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<form><field name="BAR_DateTo" type="Date">
                         <date format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss">
                             <value>2011-07-04 00:00:00</value>
                         </date>
                    </field></form>'

SELECT
    @XML.value('(/form/field[@name="BAR_DateTo"]/value)[1]', 'date') AS BARDATE
```

I'm getting NULL value as output. I'm expecting to see 2011-07-04 00:00:00 or 2011-07-04.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/form/field[@name="BAR_DateTo"]/date/value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You xpath incorrect. Try this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<field name="BAR_DateTo" type="Date">
                         <date format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss">
                             <value>2011-07-04 00:00:00</value>
                         </date>
                    </field>'
SELECT
   @XML.value('(//value)[1]', 'date') AS BARDATE
```

or you can use use full xpath if necessary:

```
SELECT
   @XML.value('(/field/date/value)[1]', 'date') AS BARDATE
```

If you want to filter `field` elements by `name` attribute, use this:

```
SELECT
   @XML.value('(/field[@name=''BAR_DateTo'']/date/value)[1]', 'date') AS BARDATE
```

It is depends how the boolean values represented in the XML. In your case you can try:

```
DECLARE @XML XML =
'<field name="BAR_corrects_prior_report" type="Boolean">
     <value>false</value>
</field>'

SELECT CASE @XML.value('(/field[@name=''BAR_corrects_prior_report''  and @type=''Boolean'']/value)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
       WHEN 'true' THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END AS BARDATE
```

Comment: Thnaks Hamlet.I have updated code below one is working for me

SELECT
   @XML.value('(//value)[1]', 'date') AS BARDATE

I have missed Double backslash 

Thanks

Comment: Hamlet,
Can you provide sample on how to read boolean value in XML?

<field name="BAR_corrects_prior_report" type="Boolean"><value>false</value></field>